# Парсер цены Python BS4

Tags: python, парсер, beautiful-soup

[![Страница][1]][1]

Необходимо спарсить цену 49990 без "Р" и чтобы это было число,а не текст
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EAbGt.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вроде как работает :D

```
import requests,fake_useragent
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://shop.mts.ru/product/smartfon-apple-iphone-11-new-128gb-fioletovyj'
user_agent = {'user-agent':fake_useragent.UserAgent().random}

responsive = requests.get(url, headers = user_agent)
html = BeautifulSoup(responsive.text, 'html.parser')
information = html.find('span',class_='product-price__current').get_text(strip=True)
price = ''
for i in information:
    if i.isdigit():
        price += i
print(price)
```

Comment: Выдает 49 990Â â½
https://shop.mts.ru/product/smartfon-apple-iphone-11-new-128gb-fioletovyj

Comment: @WETS, исправил . Так пойдёт ?

Comment: Можно проще тоже самое написать: `price = int(''.join(filter(str.isdigit, information)))`

Comment: да,спасибо все ок